# Argument error on :ets.lookup(:tzdata_current_release, :release_version) when running inside migration

Tags: elixir, ecto, tzdata

I have this piece of code:

```
case Timex.Timezone.get(data) do
  {:error, _} = error ->
    error

  data ->
    {:ok, data}
end
```

to put timezones that are saved in the database into a struct.

Well when running a migration that gets some data through an Ecto Query I get this error:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup(:tzdata_current_release, :release_version)
    lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:47: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.current_release_from_table/0
    lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:14: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.simple_lookup/1
    lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:7: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.zone_and_link_list/0
    lib/tzdata.ex:40: Tzdata.zone_exists?/1
    lib/timezone/timezone.ex:152: Timex.Timezone.name_of/1
    lib/timezone/timezone.ex:180: Timex.Timezone.get/2
    lib/common/ecto/timezone.ex:27: Common.Ecto.Timezone.load/1
    (ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:661: Ecto.Type.process_loaders/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/schema.ex:1490: Ecto.Schema.load!/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/schema.ex:1442: Ecto.Schema.safe_load_zip/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/schema.ex:1443: Ecto.Schema.safe_load_zip/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/schema.ex:1430: Ecto.Schema.__safe_load__/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:282: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.process_source/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:170: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.preprocess/5
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/query.ex:77: DBConnection.Query.Postgrex.Query.decode_map/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/query.ex:64: DBConnection.Query.Postgrex.Query.decode/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1019: DBConnection.decode/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:73: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.prepare_execute/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:256: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.sql_call/6
```

Which has that code in the stack trace and doing some Inspects can verify that that's indeed the call that triggers the error, although doing:

```
iex(1)> Timex.Timezone.get("America/Los_Angeles")
#<TimezoneInfo(America/Los_Angeles - PDT (-07:00:00))>
```

In `iex -S mix` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error happens because `Timex` needs to be started to function. This is normally done automatically if you add it to your `mix.exs` dependencies at application startup. However, in mix tasks you have to manually select which applications to start. In your custom mix tasks, you can make sure an application is started via `Application.ensure_all_started(:timex)`.

In your `ecto.migrate` case, we don't have access to the actual mix task, so we need to be a bit more creative by using mix aliases in your `mix.exs` file:

```
  def project do
    [
      ...
      aliases: aliases(),
      ...
    ] 
  end


  defp aliases do
    [
      "ecto.migrate_s": ["ecto.migrate.startup", "ecto.migrate"],
    ]
  end
```

And a Task `ecto.migrate.startup` for our `Application.ensure_all_started(:timex)`

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.Startup do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(args) do
    Mix.shell.info("Starting apps required for ecto.migrate...")
    Application.ensure_all_started(:timex)
  end
end
```

Now you should be able to run `mix ecto.migrate_s` which first starts `timex` and then runs your migrations. (This is not a perfectly clean solution, but I'm not aware of alternatives right now)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the alias could be defined as `"ecto.migrate": ["run ecto.migrate.startup", "run ecto.migrate"]` to effectively 'shadow' or override the existing task but maybe that's only possible for the builtin Mix tasks.

Comment: While this is a valid approach, in one-off scenario it is sufficient to call `Application.ensure_all_started(:timex)` in the body of the migration.